# Pass an php array to another php file with ajax

Tags: javascript, php

I want to send an array, which I got from mysql, and send it with ajax to another php file. I can't send the data to the file. I get the data in the first PHP file. But when I set an alert with the array in JS then the output is undefined. The other PHP file didn't received any data.

**PHP send to another PHP file**

```
   <?php

   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $items = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM COMPARISONFOLDER JOIN ITEM ON ITEM.COMPARISONFOLDER_ID LIKE COMPARISONFOLDER.COMPARISONFOLDER_ID WHERE COMPARISONFOLDER.COMPARISONFOLDER_ID LIKE $id");

   while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($items)) {
       $shuffledItems[] = $item;
   }
   shuffle($shuffledItems);
?>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       getItems();
   });

   function getItems() {
         var urlActiveFillSurvey = "https://vinkovic.ch/test1/activeFillSurvey.php/";
         jQuery.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: urlActiveFillSurvey,
             data: {data : '<?php echo $shuffledItems ?>'},
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             success: function(data) {
               jQuery('.data').html(data.responseText);
             },
             error: function(data) {
               jQuery('.data').html(data.responseText);
             }
         });
       }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="data"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP File which should get the array**

```
<?php
require ('../wp-blog-header.php');
$data = $_GET['data'];
echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Item 1</th>
    <th>Item 2</th>
    </tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($data[0]['ITEM']).'" width="500" height="auto"/></td>';
    echo '<td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($data[1]['ITEM']).'" width="500" height="auto"/></td>';
    echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass the id and just get the data directly in PHP file that's going to use it?It seems a bit unnecessary to first fetch the data in the back end (your PHP), send it to the front end just to send it back to the back end.'

Comment: Its because I want to live update the page without reloading it. The second PHP file is getting displayed in the first PHP file.

Comment: And if you pass the id to your second PHP file and make the query there instead, it will be the same thing, but with less data moving back and fort between the back end and front end. You will still pass the id using Ajax and get the response in the same way.

Comment: you are adding a raw php array to a javascript file

Comment: Also change the $_GET to $_POST type.. it will make your life easier having the data inside the request body of the HTTP request

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Great idea! I done that and it works now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data: {data : '<?php echo $shuffledItems ?>'},
```

is where the error is, change to

```
data: {data : '<?php echo json_encode($shuffledItems) ?>'},
```

or `base64_encode` or `url_encode` the json out put to make it url friendly

Comment: json_encode and base64_encode still display nothing. With url_encode it doesn't display the table anymore.

Comment: do console.log(data) in sucess function. am sure the data is plain html. hit Ctrl + Shift + i to view log